# Use separate capture groups for repeated matches

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to verify a CRON expression with a unique set of fields.
Each field can either be the single digit number, or one of these symbols: * /

I have such an expression: `1/6 * * * 0 */2 *`
And managed to create this pattern: `([0-9\/*]+\s??){7}`

While it works, it matches the entire string as **the match**, but there's only one capture group and it contains the last segment (*).

Is there a way to have the match return the entire string, but every segment (there's 7 of them) have a different group?

Comment: Do you have access to the .NET code? Is it in C#, VB.NET? Also, why not just `(?:\d+(?:/\d+)?|\*)` to match all occurrences ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%2f%5cd%2b%29%3f%7c%5c*%29&i=1%2f6+*+*+*+0+*%2f2+*))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's in C#

Comment: Then all captures are accessible from `match.Groups[1].Captures`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll check it out, I was using regex101 to build the pattern